# How do you filter rows in a dataframe based on the column numbers from a Python list?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns, x and y, that correspond to a large signal. It is about 3 million rows in size.

[Wavelength from dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTdk3.png)

I am trying to isolate the peaks from the signal. After using scipy, I got a 1D Python list corresponding to the indexes of the peaks. However, they are not the actual x-values of the signal, but just the index of their corresponding row:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(y, height=(None, peakline))
```

So, I decided I would just filter the original dataframe by setting all values in its y column to NaN unless they were on an index found in the peak list. I did this iteratively, however, since it is 3000000 rows, it is extremely slow:

```
peak_index = 0
for data_index in list(data.index):
    if data_index != peaks[peak_index]:
        data[data_index, 1] = float('NaN')
    else:
        peak_index += 1
```

Does anyone know what a faster method of filtering a Pandas dataframe might be?

Comment: if your data is in a list just call `isin` `df[data_index].isin(peak_index)` then apply your filter. hard to say without a [mcve]

Comment: you should be able to use `loc` or `iloc` in your case. (e.g.: `data.loc[<list_of_index>, 1] = np.nan` )

Answer (score 0):

Looping in most cases is extremely inefficient when it comes to pandas. Assuming you just need filtered DataFrame that contains the values of both `x` and `y` columns only when `y` is a peak, you may use the following piece of code:

```
df.iloc[peaks]
```

Alternatively, if you are hoping to retrieve an original DataFrame with `y` column retaining its peak values and having `NaN` otherwise, then please use:

```
df.y = df.y.where(df.y.iloc[peaks] == df.y.iloc[peaks])
```

Finally, since you seem to care about just the `x` values of the peaks, you might just rework the first piece in the following way:

```
df.iloc[peaks].x
```